# Primefaces 5: view data with datatable on two columns

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I'm using Primefaces 5 with JDK 1.8 on Glassfish server 4.1.

I create a page xhtml with following structure ():

```
<p:dataTable value="#{myBean.myList}" ...>
    <p:column>MyLabel</p:column>
    <p:column>MyImage</p:column>
    <p:column>MyDescription</p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

so I see in output a table with 3 columns:

```
label, image and description
label, image and description
label, image and description
label, image and description
label, image and description
label, image and description
...
```

Object *myList* of my bean returns about 50 rows that are displayed on my page.
How can I view this rows on 2 columns? Something as:

```
label, image and description           label, image and description
label, image and description           label, image and description
label, image and description           label, image and description
```

Thanks.

Comment: How about split the data into two lists and display 2 tables?

Comment: I would like use one table, if possible...

Comment: and what is the problem  exactly about merging MyImage and MyDescription columns?

Comment: By using one table, you will not be able to sort. You could change the style so the two tables look like one.

Comment: What other features of the datatable do you want to use?

Comment: `<p:dataGrid columns="2">`

Comment: @Balusc: Can I use datagrid as container of datatable?

Answer (score 0):

You should put into datagrid.

```
   <p:dataGrid value="#{myBean.myList}" columns="3" layout="grid" paginator="true" ...>
    <p:column>MyLabel</p:column>
    <p:column>MyImage</p:column>
    <p:column>MyDescription</p:column>
   </p:dataGrid>
```

https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/dataGrid.xhtml

Answer (score -1):

Define an auxiliary class which wraps two entities in one object:

```
public class DoubleItem{

    private String label;
    private String imageUrl;
    private String description;

    private String label2;
    private String imageUrl2;
    private String description2;

    //Getters & setters

}
```

Then in your managed bean initialization you make the conversion from your current list to a `List<DoubleItem>`, so you can iterate over it in the view:

```xhtml
<p:dataTable value="#{myBean.doubleItemList}" var="doubleItem">
    <p:column>#{doubleItem.label}</p:column>
    <p:column>#{doubleItem.imageUrl}</p:column>
    <p:column>#{doubleItem.description}</p:column>
    <p:column>#{doubleItem.label2}</p:column>
    <p:column>#{doubleItem.imageUrl2}</p:column>
    <p:column>#{doubleItem.description2}</p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```